# AngularJS ng-options with variable amount of ng-models possible?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am having a formular with a label, a select and a button. The thing is this part should be variable, so it should be possible to add this row as many times as needed:

```
<div class="form-group" ng-repeat="cLine in cLines">
    <label class="col-xs-6 control-label">{{cLine.cName}}</label> 
    <div class="col-xs-6">
         <div class="input-group">
            <select ng-model="<!-- first try: -->cLine.cColor for cLine in cLines" class="form-control" id='polylineColor' ng-options="color.name for color in colors"></select>
            <span class="btn btn-default input-group-addon" style="background-color:white;" ng-click="addNewObject()">
                     +
            </span>
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now there is a "control row" with Save button, Reset and an Add Button to add these lines. 
Between those there is a "config row" almost the same as the first one, but instead of a label there is a textfield to enter the name of that element.

Markup looks as follows:

```
<!-- Mask -->
<div class="form-inline" style="padding-bottom: 10px;">
    <input type="text" class="form-control text-center" placeholder="Type name here.." />
    <select ng-model="selectedColorX" class="form-control" id='polylineColor' ng-options="color.name for color in colors"></select>
</div>
<!-- Control-->
<div class="form-group" ng-show="AuthSvcs.isCurrentUserRoleIn([USER_ROLE.edit])">
    <div class="text-center">
              <!-- TODO: "Add counting line" -->
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="addLine()" ng-disabled="" ng-bind="TranslationSvcs.tr.STR_ADD_LINE"></button>     
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="save()" ng-disabled="countingForm.$invalid || countingForm.$pristine" ng-bind="TranslationSvcs.tr.STR_SAVE"></button>
              <button type="cancel" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="reset()" ng-disabled="countingForm.$pristine" ng-bind="TranslationSvcs.tr.STR_RESET"></button>
     </div>
</div>
```

So initially there is none or maybe one line with a label, the select and the add button. Then I want to type in the name, choose a color(from the select) and click "Add" so there should appear a new row.

The problem is how to wire the selects? Because the ng-model for the select resp. the ng-options is variable so I cannot wire static $scope.selected or something like that.

Right now I have my controller as follows:

```
$scope.cLines = [
                     { id: 1, cColor: "red", cName: "Line 1" },
                     { id: 2, cColor: "red", cName: "Line 2" },
                     { id: 3, cColor: "red", cName: "Line 3" }
                  ];  

$scope.cColor = 0;
$scope.colors = [ {name: "red"}, {name: "blue"}, {name: "pink"}];
$scope.selectedColor1 = $scope.cLines.cColor;
$scope.selectedColor2 = $scope.colors[2]; //pink
$scope.selectedColor3 = $scope.colors[0]; //red
$scope.selectedColorX = $scope.colors[0]; //blue
```

So usually the solution with the "selectedColor.." cannot work. As one can see above I am trying to link the variable ng-models of the X selects/ng-options to the *$scope.cLines.cColor* but unfortunately that does not work.

Can anyone help or is it possible at all?

Comment: Are there multiple control and configuration rows?

Comment: No. It is just one config row which is always there where you can type the name, select the color and then click in the one control row the "Add" button to add a line with the name and color which was chosen.

Comment: The thing is, I want the color stil changeable after the line was added, so I need for every new row the new ng-model connected to the select. Preferable for sure if possible also so that the label is no label but a textfield with the new content or changeable content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest pushing the new data into the existing array.
When you add a new entry, make an object with the same format with existing items, so you can handle the logic together.

When creating a new select, it is possible to reuse the ng-options, and they won't interfere with each other. Save the selected option into the data object itself.

```
$scope.add = function() {
  $scope.clines.push({
    id: $scope.clines.length + 1, // assuming the id starts from 1 and not missing any, else you have to generate your own id
    cName: $scope.name,
    cColor: $scope.color
  });
}
```

For HTML you can ng-repeat the data array and use the cColor itself as the ng-model

```
<div ng-repeat="data in clines">
  {{data.id}}.
  {{data.cName}}
  <select ng-model='data.cColor' ng-options="color.name as color.name for color in colors"></select>
</div>
```

[Full fiddle](http://jsbin.com/rihitizati/1/edit?html,js,output)

It is also possible to put new data into a separate array, by using separate ng-repeat, or concat the array and use same ng-repeat.

Answer (score 1):

Use am array for the selected colors. Each index will match with the cLines array, so it will be easy to manipulate.

// template.js

```
 <div class="form-group" ng-repeat="cLine in cLines">
        <label class="col-xs-6 control-label">{{cLine.cName}}</label> 
        <div class="col-xs-6">
             <div class="input-group">
                <select ng-model="selecteColors[$index]" class="form-control" id='polylineColor' ng-options="color.name for color in colors"></select>
                <span class="btn btn-default input-group-addon" style="background-color:white;" ng-click="addNewObject()">
                         +
                </span>
             </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

//controller.js

```
$scope.cLines = [
                     { id: 1, cColor: "red", cName: "Line 1" },
                     { id: 2, cColor: "red", cName: "Line 2" },
                     { id: 3, cColor: "red", cName: "Line 3" }
                  ];  

$scope.cColor = 0;
$scope.colors = [ {name: "red"}, {name: "blue"}, {name: "pink"}];
$scope.selecteColors = (function () {
  var defaultColors = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < $scope.clines.length; i++) {
    defaultColors.push($scope.colors[0].name);
  }
  return defaultColors;
})();
```

Comment: But where is the connection from the existing cLines objects to the selectedColors array? In other words, if I have existing cLines with the cColors, how does the selectedColors array gets them and pre selects them? To be fair, that was not obviously mentioned.

Comment: Angular takes care for you in the ngModel with the `$index` variable inside the ngRepeat. The first time will be undefined, but that's ok, or you could just remap it at the beginning. I updated the code so each one has a default color assign

Comment: ok I haven't completely tried the new version but the solution of @Icycool is quite simple and it works. Thank you very much anyways and maybe in some other situations this helps someone else :)

Answer (score 1):

Make your row model this

```
    $scope.cLines = [
       { id: 1, cColor: "red", cName: "Line 1" ,
         colors:$scope.colors },
       { id: 2, cColor: "red", cName: "Line 2" ,
         colors:$scope.colors },
       { id: 3, cColor: "red", cName: "Line 3",
         colors:$scope.colors }
       ];
```

And make sure when you add the row in addNewObject(), you copy the values of the `colors` array.
Also change the select to

```
<div class="col-xs-6">
         <div class="input-group">
            <select ng-model="cLine.cColor" class="form-control" id='polylineColor' ng-options="color.name for color in cLine.colors"></select>
            <span class="btn btn-default input-group-addon" style="background-color:white;" ng-click="addNewObject()">
                     +
            </span>
         </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: This seems to be also a good solution, but the one from @Icycool is a bit better in my situation because I won't need an extra field in the cLines object. Thank you

Comment: Indeed..I started with something like that but for some reason ended up thinking the array was needed in each row.